# How can I extract the SSID's of available networks, using the nmcli command

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm trying to build a script to allow user to choose from available network present, using :

```
nmcli device wifi
```

showing 2 networks ( as an exapmple in current location ):

[image]

How can I extract the only the name ( SSID ) of available networks ?

Comment: `nmcli` provides fine-grained control over its output using the `-f` or `--fields` command line option - for example `nmcli -f SSID device wifi` or `nmcli --fields SSID device wifi`

Comment: @steeldriver ^ You could have fooled me that is an answer  :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm but it's not an answer to *"Extract content from text file"* ;) I guess it's the ol' XY problem again. . .

Comment: @steeldriver you are right at that, but I'd take the freedom to edit the title a bit, since what OP needs is not what he is asking for.

Comment: @steeldriver I did it ^ feel free :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm probably it can be solved in several ways. How could it be done if it was a text file?

Comment: @Guy.D Maybe something like `nmcli device wifi | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v SSID` ? I'm not sure if the first column of `*` actually counts as a column.

Comment: @Guy.D If it were a textfile, you'd have to ask another question. what you ask is how to extract from cli output, specifically from `nmcli` even. Apart from the (prvious) title, this question has nothing to do with a text file.

Comment: @JacobVlijm well, you've changed the title of this q. At first I've save the result to a text file, and then tried to extract ssid

Comment: @Guy.D That was not in the question :), and is not needed to extract data from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `nmcli` program provides fine-grained control over its output using the `-f` or `--fields` command line option.

For example `nmcli -f SSID device wifi` or `nmcli --fields SSID device wifi` will list just the values of the SSID field for all available networks.

If you are processing the output in a script, you may want to look at the `-t` (`--terse`) option, which strips the header, and the `-m` (`--mode`) option option, which provides output as key:value pairs.

Comment: A great shortcut is using the `--get-value` option which is a shortcut for `--mode tabular --terse --fields` and and just prints the value without any headers at all so you just get the pure value